# How to explan this javascript method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I am using react and have a no state component named "Button.jsx", And I will send a function (by props) to the button component like this:

**app.jsx**

```
addValue(){
    console.log("add")
}
```

`<Button className="btn btn-primary" text="click" action={this.addValue}/>`

in **Button.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Button extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.action = this.action.bind(this);
  }
  action(e){
    // console.log(this.props.action)
    const {props} = this,{action = ()=>{}} = props;
    action()
  }
    render() {
      return (
        <button className={this.props.className} onClick={this.action}>{this.props.text}</button>
      )
    }
}
```

I know it works(execute `addValue()`). But how? the key point is on the `action(e)` function, can anyone explan?

Comment: why would anybody use "react" for `<button class="classname" onClick="action(this)">text</button>` ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass some values (string, number or function) into react component property (for example `<Button text="click" action={this.addValue}/>`). You can get it inside this component like `this.props.` + name of the property. As for `Button` component mentioned above, `this.props.text` returns `click` string, and `this.props.action` returns `addValues` function (you definde it in parent component), which you can call with `()` - `this.props.action()`;

There are some special properties in react.js. Properties for handling some events: `onClick`, `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseMove` etc. You can pass into this property a function and this function will be executed when the appropriate event will be triggered. In your example, you pass the component method `action` to `onClick` property.

In `action` method there is some es6 magic. It's called **Object destructuring**, you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) about it. When you have some object, you can assign the values of the properties of this object to the variables with the same name this way:

```
var object = {p: 42, q: true};
var {p, q, d = 'default' } = object;

console.log(p); // 42
console.log(q); // true
console.log(d); // 'default'
```

You also can specify some default value `d = 'default'` if the object do not have a property with `d` name in variable `d` will be assigned the string `default`. If for some reason one will not pass a value to `action` component property, this code: `const {props} = this, {action = ()=>{}} = props;` assign noop function `() => {}` to `action` variable and calling `action()` do not throw the error.

Thus, in your case, you can rewrite it:

```
action(e){
  const {props} = this,{action = ()=>{}} = props;
  action()
}
```

to:

```
action(e){
  const props = this.props;
  const action = props.action || (() => {});

  action();
}
```

Look at this example in action here - https://jsfiddle.net/kxrkddmm/

Comment: thanks you so much^^,very clearly to  solved my  question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but I can walk you through it:

- In your parent component (app.jsx), you are passing down a function (`addValue`) to your child component (button.jsx), which logs 'add' when called. Note that you are passing down the `addValue` function as the props `action`: `action={this.addValue}`
- In your child component (button.jsx), you now have access to that function (`addValue`).
- In the button component, you know define another function (`action`), which you pass down to the `onClick` of the `button` in your render.
- In your `action` function, you access the props from the context: `const {props} = this`, then you get the `action` function from the props: `{action = ()=>{}} = props`.
- The naming of this scenario might be confusing, since you are passing down `addValue` as `action`, and then define a local `action` in the child, which calls the other `action`, which was passed down. With this setup, your button.jsx has `this.action` and `this.props.action`, which both do the same thing in the end.

Therefore, your Button.jsx could look like this and do the same thing:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Button extends React.Component{
    render() {
      return (
        <button className={this.props.className} onClick={this.props.action}>{this.props.text}</button>
      )
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you got confused by having two `action` in your button.jsx.

Hope that helped, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: oh ya...i make a circle for myself,you break the loop for that. It's a better way to improve my code. Thanks^^